# +[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles::forStoreMetadata:] always returns nil

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I've got a Core Data model with 15 versions. It's got code to progressively migrate from the current store's version to the latest version on launch.

Key to that is a call to

```
    NSDictionary* options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @true,
                               NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @true };
    NSDictionary* sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
                                        metadataForPersistentStoreOfType: inType
                                        URL: inSourceStore
                                        options: options
                                        error: outError];
    NSManagedObjectModel* model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles: @[ [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] ]
                                                        forStoreMetadata: inSourceMetadata];
```

But that's always returning nil, and I'm not sure why. The existing store is version 14, the new model is version 15.

Now, the last change to the model was fairly trivial (the addition of a couple optional fields), so I would have thought it could infer the mapping automatically, but that wasn't working, so I added a mapping model from version 14 to version 15 using Xcode's assistant for that, and made no changes.

Any idea why it's returning nil, or what I can do to investigate this further?

In the same vein, when I say "version 14", I'm referring to the sequential numbering of the `.xcdatamodel` files. Is there any way to look at the actual store and determine which version of the model Core Data thinks it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. It turns out, I edited the latest model version, rather than adding a new one. That's why none would match. Once I reverted the latest version and added a new model version with the changes, it worked fine, even without the default mapping models.

I figured this out by testing each model to see if it matched against the source metadata, using the following:

```
    NSDictionary* storeHashes = [sourceMetadata objectForKey: NSStoreModelVersionHashesKey];
    NSArray<NSURL*>* urls = [self getModelURLs];
    urls = [urls sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                    ^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2)
                    {
                            NSURL* s2 = obj1;
                            NSURL* s1 = obj2;
                            return [s1.lastPathComponent compare: s2.lastPathComponent options: NSNumericSearch];
                    }];

    for (NSURL* url in urls)
    {
        NSDictionary* modelHashes = [self getHashesForModelAtURL: url];

        //  Compare the hashes…

        bool matches = true;
        for (NSString* entityKey in storeHashes.allKeys)
        {
            NSString* storeHash = storeHashes[entityKey];
            NSString* modelHash = modelHashes[entityKey];
            if (![storeHash isEqual: modelHash])
            {
                NSLogDebug(@"Model %@ has mismatch on %@", url.lastPathComponent, entityKey);
                matches = false;
            }
        }

        if (matches)
        {
            NSLogDebug(@"Version matches: %@", url.lastPathComponent);
            break;
        }
    }

- (NSArray<NSURL*>*)
getModelURLs
{
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]];
    NSArray<NSURL*>* urls = [bundle URLsForResourcesWithExtension: @"mom" subdirectory: @"Model.momd"];
    return urls;
}

- (NSDictionary*)
getHashesForModelAtURL: (NSURL*) inURL
{
    NSManagedObjectModel* model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: inURL];
    NSDictionary* hashes = model.entityVersionHashesByName;
    return hashes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you seem like you know what you are doing, having survived through 14 Core Data migrations and all.  So I think you should be on the lookout for some silly forehead-slapping type of mistake.

Ensure that `[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]]` is returning the expected bundle, which contains a directory `Contents/Resources/YourModelName.momd`, and that this directory contains all of the required `.mom` files (one for each version), and a `VersionInfo.plist` file.  My builds also contain a `.omo` file for the latest version only.

Now I shall answer your second question, which indeed may help you to answer your first question.

In that `VersionInfo.plist` file you will find a dictionary named `NSManagedObjectModel_VersionHashes`, which in turn contains sub-dictionaries, one key for each version.  Each version sub-dictionary contains a key for each of your entity names and value which is a 32-byte (256 bit) hash of the attributes and relationships of that entity in that version.  Let's call this these the *model hashes*.

Now open up a store database file with a SQLite viewer, or the `sqlite3` command line tool.  In that database, alongside one table for each of the entities in the model, you will see a table named `Z_METADATA` with one row and three columns.  The value of the column named `Z_PLIST` is typed as a blob of binary data.  Copy that data to a file, name it with extension `.plist`, doubleclick and, surprise it opens in your favorite plist editor because that data is in fact a string of text representing an Apple property list in XML format.  The value of its key `NSStoreModelVersionHashes` is in fact a sub-dictionary which is just like the sub-dictionary in the `VersionInfo.plist` file.  Let's call this the *store hashes*.  The 32-byte (256-bit) version hash is Base64 encoded.  (There are 44 Base64 characters.  Since each Base64 character represents 6 bits, 44 characters can represent up to 44*6 = 264 bits.)

Finally, to answer your second question, the `storeMetadata` passed to `+[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:forStoreMetadata:]` is in fact the `Z_METADATA` from the store, which contains those *store hashes*.  `+[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:forStoreMetadata:]` compares these *store hashes* to the *model hashes* from each candidate data model in the passed-in `bundle`, and returns the model whose *model hashes* match the *store hashes* for all entities, with no extra unmatched entities on either side.

So you see it's kind of tedious to do the comparison manually.  But probably while spelunking through these plists you will find that forehead-slapper.  If not, give us some more context around that code you pasted and probably someone can help.

Comment: You may have been composing that answer while I posted mine. Sorry for wasting your time! In any case, I figured it out (you can see it was user error all along). You've provided some useful info about the SQLite DB, though, thanks!

Comment: No problem, Rick.  It was not a waste.  Sometimes this happens.